# Android Studio shortcut for autocomplete Toast(Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

I have a problem with the newest version of Android Studio(> 3) to use the autocomplete for Toast with Kotlin.

In older versions with Java, it was like typing "Toast", then pushing "Tab" button on keyboard to autocomplete this.

Now, in the versions of Android Studio > 3 and Kotlin it is not working.

Anyone know how to achive this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to `Settings` > `Live Templates`. Under `Android`, find `Toast` and select it. At the bottom of settings dialog, it says `Applicable in Java`. Click `Change` button next to it and select `Statement` under `Kotlin`. Done.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Gitter!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer for your question but if you are using the [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)
library from Jetbrains (and why wouldn't you?) you can simply show a toast with the line `toast("some text")`

Comment: should this be done manually for every live template? How to apply this for all templates?